# TabControl and TabPages

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a new control. I need a header and a container inside that control that at desing time the user can add controls into. So i decided on deriving from the `TabControl` because it has both, a header zone and a container (`TabPage`) usable by the user. Although this is now becoming a problem.

My derived control like the `TabControl` when is being dragged in a form it automatically adds 2 `TabPage`. With my extensive test of writting `this.TabPages.Clear()` in every overridable methods i could find i assume that this is not in my control directly from the control code. I assume it might be from the autogenerated code. Is there a way to bypass this autogenerated code and force to only have 1 `TabPage`.

Is there a better control to derive from that give this behavior. I am delivering a control library so everything need to be inside the control code itself and it need to be able to contain control with a header and that inner container must be able to be disable without the main control being disable (main control need to still be receiving mouse and key events)

Comment: a groupbox maybe?

Comment: The `TabControlDesigner` adds the two TabPages when initialized. You can build a custom Designer and override `InitializeNewComponent()` -- If you're on .NET 5+, adding a custom designer (that is recognized) may imply some more work...

Comment: ...but the `TabControlDesigner` might be defined as `internal`, now that I think about it